# How to run a script on every page change in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue, nuxtjs

I’m currently having an issue with bootstrapvue where the menu selected from a drop down in the collapsed menu stays open after loading a new page I figure I can just manually remove the classes if I can run it on every page change with nuxt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options, but custom routing middleware sounds good.

Go to you source directory and create file `middleware/menu.js` (create dir if you not exists):

```js
export default function({route, from, store, redirect}) {
  // here put logic to hide menu
}
```

In the next step you need to setup global middleware in config. Open `nuxt.config.js` and add:

```js
router: { middleware: ['menu'] }
```

Middleware code will run before render each page.